# Django - Show dates of appointments

Tags: django, list, loops, datetime, django-queryset

I want to show dates that appointments are not booked in a template. For this reason i have so far:

```
# Collect only the dates so that i can find what is not in that range.
example_dates = Appointment.objects.values_list('start_appointment', flat=True)

# Initialize start and end date
start_date = datetime.date.today()
end_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=5)

# Initialize new list that will include records does not exists
not_found_dates = []

# Loop through in date range and if date does not exists 
# Create a dict and add it to the list
for n in range(int((end_date - start_date).days)):
    new_date = start_date + datetime.timedelta(days=n)
    if new_date not in not_found_dates:
        not_found_dates.append(new_date)
        print(new_date)

# Get original queryset
examples = Appointment.objects.filter(start_appointment__range=(start_date, end_date)).values('start_appointment')
print(examples)

# Convert it to a list
examples = list(examples)

return render(request, 'appointments/add-appointment.html', {'examples': examples, 'not_found_dates': not_found_dates})
```

When i print the `new_date` from the loop i got:
2021-11-22
2021-11-23
2021-11-24
2021-11-25
2021-11-26

And the query from `examples` returns that i have 3 appointments in db in that range (2)on 2021-11-23 and (1) on 2021-11-22.

Is it possible to show the dates that appointments not booked i.e **2021-11-24, 2021-11-25, 2021-11-26**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get a list of dates within a defined timeframe (with duration of num_days) with dates that are not part of the query:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta

num_days = 5
start_date = date.today()
timeframe = [start_date + timedelta(days=d) for d in range(num_days)]
exclude = list(Transaction.objects.values_list("start_appointment", flat=True).distinct())

set(timeframe) - set(exclude)
```

Comment: Thank you for help but this is not what i want. I want to show the dates that there are no appointments in the num_days. This shows appointments in the num_days and excludes the rest.

Comment: No it's the opposite. It should be what you need. It excludes appointment dates from a given timeframe. So now you get all available days.

Comment: Yes I am sure. It seems that you store datetime in your models and not only date. Would be good to have such information at the beginning of the post. You can change your query to use `"start_appointment__date"`. This will return date instead of datetime.

Comment: You are right mate! Sorry for not getting that right. Thanks for help.